# How to remove site content from quick launch

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I would like to remove site content from quick launch?

I've followed below article but couldn't find my Master Page in Site Settings..
How do I enable it?

< http://3sharp.com/blog/removing-the-site-contents-link-from-the-quick-launch/ >

Comment: Can you find `site settings` > `Master pages and page layouts`?

Comment: Hi Mark.. Yes.. I just found it was located in Web Designer Galleries > Master pages... But I found so many folders.. what would be my next step?

Comment: By default you are using seattle.master (you can double check at `site settings>Master page`). Download it, modify it, and upload it back. I highly suggest you read some tutorial before you actually do it. (e.g. [this one](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/29/edit-existing-master-page-to-change-logo-hide-top-suite-links-etc-in-sharepoint-2013/)) BTW, you can modify the seattle.html instead of seattle.master but it is not easy to discuss this way. You can search for "html master page"

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this code on your `seattle.html` page and then publish it.

But don't forget to make the copy of that seattle.html & master page before you make any changes.

Apply that copy of master page to your site, by setting that master page as default, instead of directly making the changes to the original.

Try making & applying copy of that seattle html master page instead,

```
 .ms-core-listMenu-item, .ms-core-listMenu-item:link, .ms-core-listMenu-item:visited, .ms-tv-item:link, .ms-tv-item:visited, .ms-tv-header:link, .ms-tv-header:visited {
        color: #666666;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly remove Site Contents from navigation settings. Please follow the below steps :

1. GoTo http://example.com/_layouts/15/areanavigationsettings.aspx
   (i.e. append '/_layouts/15/areanavigationsettings.aspx' to your webAbsoluteUrl OR siteAbsoluteUrl )
2. Select Site Content >> Delete
   [image]
3. Click OK
4. Done

I Hope this will help you out.

Comment: The link will automatically added back when new content is added to the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can even add this CSS to your site

```
  #sideNavBox a[href$="/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"]
 {
    display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Site Settings, Under Look and Feel, there is something called Tree View.

From there you can disable the Tree View and all the Site Contents will be hidden.